# embedded development with tiva-c

Tags: ros, arduino, embedded, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using tiva-c board, and using its hardware quadrature encoder and publishing odometry from the tiva-c. My question is where to go from here? If we want do develop embedded ros, are we confined to arduino and tiva-c boards or are there better and more advanced alternatives?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246737/embedded-development-with-tiva-c/) by [wintermute](https://answers.ros.org/users/26115/wintermute/) on ROS Answers with karma: 180 on 2016-10-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosserial is designed to connect an embedded board to ROS on a full-featured Linux computer. If you're not using a larger computer and Linux, then you don't need to be limited by rosserial.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0